# C reading a file with null in it

Tags: c, posix, nul

I'm working on a data file that contains a fixed number of characters followed by a colon and then a number. All of the first four characters can be anything from all nulls to all (char)255s.

However, when trying to read it, I'm having trouble determining the EOF.

If I use posix's `read(2)` like so:

```
ssize_t letters_read = read(fd, buf, 4);
```

Then letters_read is set to 0. The man page says that means I've reached an EOF; however, this is simply not true.

If I use `fread(3)` in a similar way, then I still get zero as a return value. Even when sending the file to `feof(3)`, it says I'm at the end of file.

Now, if I just ignore the return values, then I'm able to continue reading the file and get further results.

How would I be able to read all four nulls and still be able to know when I've reached an eof?

A small excerpt of the file looks like this:

```
4
(null)(null)(null)(null):4
(null)(null)(null)(null):40
(null)(null)(null)(null):402
Af*8:3004
```

**UPDATE**
As per request, here is how I'm going about collecting data:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void process_characters(char *data);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *input_file = argv[1];

  int opt = 0;

  int input_fd = open(input_file, O_RDONLY);

  FILE *temp_fd = fopen(input_file, "r");

  unsigned long character_size = 0;

  fscanf(temp_fd, "%l", character_size);


  char data[character_size];

  //gobble up the first line
  do
  {
    read(input_fd, data, 1);
    printf("%i\n", data[0]);
  } while(data[0] != '\n');

  size_t characters_read = 0;
  characters_read = read(input_fd, data, character_size);
  //while(feof(temp_fd) != 0)

  while(characters_read != 0)
  {

    //fread(data, sizeof(char), character_size, temp_fd);
    process_characters(data);
    ///gobble up the garbage
    do
    {
      read(input_fd, data, 1);
      printf("%i\n", data[0]);
    }while(data[0] != 10);

    characters_read = read(input_fd, data, character_size);
  }

  fclose(temp_fd);
  close(input_fd);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you get zero from read, there is no data left to read. How did you open the file?  It could be that you zapped the file, or it is positioned at the end. Please provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Some of the conclusions you have asserted are either incorrect or missing context.

Comment: How is the file open?  Posting a complete minimal code would be useful.

Comment: If you're in Windows make sure to open file with `b` in the open mode

Comment: As per request, I've updated the original post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @melpomene how does the update not contain a mcve?

Comment: An mcve should be a complete program that we can download, compile, and run. You have no `main` function and  no `#include` directives. It's hard to tell what else you thought you could safely omit -- but apparently that includes the definition and initialization of `input_file`, and  any code that displays any results.

Comment: @KeithThompson That might get turn the question into a code dump. Would it be better to put the full thing in a pastebin?

Comment: No, it would  not. The code needs to be in the body of the question. Please read [mcve] if you haven't already.

Comment: That's missing how you're running the program, any input files it needs, and a description of the problematic behavior.

Comment: Your updated code, though it's a complete program, does not compile. You need to copy-and-paste your *exact* code. (You define `input_fd` twice, and `"%l"` is not a valid format.)

Comment: Your updated code still doesn't compile. `print_map(my_hoffman);` -- What is `print_map`? What is `my_hoffman`?

Comment: @KeithThompson It's irrelevant. The focus of the problem was based on the read function. The call to print_map doesn't have anything to do with the problem at hand.  

Look at where the call is: at the end of the program right before the files close. Every read took place before the print_map function. Also, realize that data is a local variable and is not passed as a parameter to the function.

Comment: If it's irrelevant, you shouldn't have included it in the question. Posting code that doesn't compile (unless a compilation failure is the problem you're asking about) means you don't have an MCVE. If I wanted to try your program myself, I'd have to edit it first. If you want people to help you, do that work yourself before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
  unsigned long character_size = 0;

  fscanf(temp_fd, "%l", character_size);
```

... has an invalid format specified, and needs to provide the variable address rather than its value. `"%l"` does not specify a type to read. Perhaps you want `"%lu"` which is for an unsigned long integer, which is how `character_size` is defined. `character_size` should be `&character_size`.

However, there is no such (decimal) value at the beginning of the sample file you have provided, so it is unclear what this `fscanf` line is really supposed to do.

(You claimed that using read as follow returns 0:

```
ssize_t letters_read = read(fd, buf, 4);
```

However, there is no such line in your code).

Comment: When changing it to %lu, I receive a segfault.

Comment: `fscanf(temp_fd, "%ld", &character_size);`  It needs the address of the variable, not the contents of it as the parameter

Comment: @infixed indeed, I missed that. Thanks, edited.

Comment: @SailorCire see edit.

Comment: The &character_size solved it.